# wpf bind to selected listview item and update another list based on that selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, I'm trying to teach myself the MVVM pattern, and I'm hitting a road block. My code is loosely based off of Josh Smiths article, I'm using it to help me learn MVVM and create a small app for work in the process.

What I'm trying to accomplish:
I've bound a viewmodel to a listview showing a list of products, each product has a list of "productTemplate" items.  In my View I would like this list to populate inside a listbox when a product from my list view is selected. I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.  I think I'm just missing something simple but I'm not sure.

My code:
Two Models (Product, ProductTemplateItem);

```
public class Product  {

    private string _productNum;
    private string _productFamily;

    public Product() {    
    }

    public string ProductNum { get; set; }

    public string ProductFamily { get; set; }

}

public class ProductTemplateItem : ChangeEventHandlerBase {

    private string _TemplateItem;
    private string _TemplateCode;

    public ProductTemplateItem(string templateItem, string templateCode) {
        _TemplateItem = templateItem;
        _TemplateCode = templateCode;
    }

    public string TemplateItem {
        get { return _TemplateItem; }
        set { if(_TemplateItem != value) {
                _TemplateItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TemplateItem");
            }
        }
    }

    public string TemplateCode {
        get { return _TemplateCode; }
        set {
            if (_TemplateCode != value) {
                _TemplateCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TemplateCode");
            }
        }
    }

    public override string DisplayName {
        get {
            return $"{TemplateItem} - {TemplateCode}";
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModels (Product View Model, brings everything together and adds the product template list, and AlProductsViewModel adds data and exposes everything to be bound in XAML):

```
public class ProductViewModel : BaseViewModel {

    private Product _product;
    private bool _isSelected;
    private List<ProductTemplateItem> _productTemplate;

    public ProductViewModel(string productNum, string productFamily) {
        Product.ProductNum = productNum;
        Product.ProductFamily = productFamily;
        _productTemplate = new List<ProductTemplateItem>();
    }

    public string ProductNumber {
        get { return _product.ProductNum; }
        set { if(_product.ProductNum != value) {
                _product.ProductNum = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProductNumber");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ProductFamily {
        get { return _product.ProductFamily; }
        set {
            if (_product.ProductFamily != value) {
                _product.ProductFamily = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProductFamily");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set {
            if (_isSelected != value) {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    public List<ProductTemplateItem> ProductTemplate {
        get { return _productTemplate; }
        set { if (_productTemplate != value) {
                _productTemplate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProductTemplate");
            }
        }
    }

    public Product Product {
        get {
            if (_product == null) {
                _product = new Product();
                return _product;
            }
            else {
                return _product;
            }
        }
        set { if(_product != value) {
                _product = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Product");
            }
        }
    }

    public override string DisplayName {
        get {
            return Product.ProductNum;
        }
    }

}

public class AllProductsViewModel : BaseViewModel{

    public AllProductsViewModel() {
        AddProducts();
    }

    private void AddProducts() {

        List<ProductViewModel> all = new List<ProductViewModel>();

        all.Add(new ProductViewModel("4835", "Crop Cart"));
        all.Add(new ProductViewModel("780", "Piler"));
        all.Add(new ProductViewModel("880", "Piler"));
        all.Add(new ProductViewModel("150", "Scooper"));

        all[0].ProductTemplate.Add(new Model.ProductTemplateItem("Miscellaneous","MISC"));
        all[0].ProductTemplate.Add(new Model.ProductTemplateItem("Drawbar", "DRBR"));
        all[0].ProductTemplate.Add(new Model.ProductTemplateItem("Mainframe", "FRAM"));
        all[0].ProductTemplate.Add(new Model.ProductTemplateItem("Conveyor", "CONV"));

        all[1].ProductTemplate.Add(new Model.ProductTemplateItem("Hello", "HELL"));

        AllProducts = new ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>(all);

    }

    public ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> AllProducts { get; private set; }

}
```

And my XAML code which is a user control with a ListView based off of Josh's code and a listbox that needs to be updated based off of the selection in the ListView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Parts_Book_Tool.Views.ProductsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Parts_Book_Tool.Views"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Parts_Book_Tool.ViewModel"
         xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:AllProductsViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ProductGroups" Source="{Binding Path=AllProducts}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ProductFamily"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ProductFamily" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <GroupStyle x:Key="ProductGroupStyle">
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    Margin="1"
                    Padding="4,2,0,2"
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
    <Style x:Key="MainHCCStyle" TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border 
                        Background="{StaticResource Brush_HeaderBackground}" 
                        BorderBrush="LightGray" 
                        BorderThickness="1" 
                        CornerRadius="5" 
                        Margin="4" 
                        Padding="4" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                        >
                        <TextBlock 
                            FontSize="14"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Foreground="White" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                            />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ProductItemsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <!-- 
  Stretch the content of each cell so that we can 
  right-align text in the Total Sales column. 
  -->
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <!-- 
  Bind the IsSelected property of a ListViewItem to the 
  IsSelected property of a CustomerViewModel object.
  -->
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="Model Info" Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView  x:Name="lvModelNumbers" Margin="6,2,6,50" DataContext="{StaticResource ProductGroups}" 
                   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ProductItemsStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="ProductGroupStyle"/>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Model Number" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="Model Template" Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem/ProductTemplate, ElementName=lvModelNumbers}" Margin="6,2,6,50">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</Grid>
```

It feels to me like I'm missing the capture of an event to update the listbox, but with my inexperience in MVVM I Can't be sure.  I've tried binding to the SelectedItem of the named element but that doesn't work.  I can get the listbox to populate if I bind "AllProducts/ProductTemplate", but it just gives me the first indexed values, and doesn't dynamically change when I select another product.

Hopefully that is enough information, and any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm enjoying learning MVVM but it's dificult to wrap my head around.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bind the `ListBox` to the `ProductTemplate` property of the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView`:

```
<ListView  x:Name="lvModelNumbers" Margin="6,2,6,50"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductGroups}}" 
                   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ProductItemsStyle}">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="ProductGroupStyle"/>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Model Number" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.ProductTemplate, ElementName=lvModelNumbers}" Margin="6,2,6,50">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I could have swore I tried that lol, all i had to do was replace the / for a . on the SelectedItem binding and it worked.  This should probably be on another thread but it applies here.  so does / bind to the field and .(period) bind to the property?